# What are the essentials of a Subnet mask?

Tags: networking, subnet

What is the use of a subnet mask?

What is the below output conveying to the user?

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
 IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Basically, why do I need Subnet mask when I have my IP?

Comment: EA over at SF has answered this much better than anyone else I've ever seen. http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Answer (score 25):

If you think of your IP address like a phone number:

- the subnet mask tells you how many digits are part of the area code
- the remaining digits are your individual number under that area code

Comment: Nice succinct example that explains the purpose without getting technical.

Answer (score 18):

### Brief

You subnet mask is used to **define your local network or [subnetwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)**. You can access everything within the same subnet directly, but everything that is not on your subnet requires the request to go via a **gateway**.

So, for a home user your subnet will be your home network - your computers and wireless devices can all talk directly to one-another. But, the internet is outside your subnet, so all communication has to go via your gateway (usually a router) first.

### Slightly Technical

A subnet is a 32-bit long [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) (as touched upon by [Manaf Abo.Rous](https://superuser.com/questions/186850/what-is-the-essentialness-of-subnet-mask/186852#186852)), normally written as four 8-bit bytes. Note that `255` is `11111111` (8 ones) in binary.

The mask basically means **"only those IP addresses that have the same numbers in the places, as defined by the subnet mask, are in my local network"**.

So a subnet of `255.255.255.0` means every IP address that matches the first three bytes is your local network, with your given numbers this is anything matching `192.168.001.###`. Alternatively a wider subnet of `255.255.0.0` would make your local network `192.168.###.###`.

### More Technical

The byte values don't *always* have to be 255, you could have `255.255.255.240`, which is 28 one's and 4 zero's. This means the first 28 bits of another IP must match your's to be in the same subset. A subnet mask must *always* be a certain number of 1's followed by only zeros to make 32-bits, and this is why it can be represented as `/28` as well (in this case anyway) with the value showing how many 1's the mask contains - this is normally used in the context of the IP, such as `192.168.1.2/28`

So, if your IP is `192.168.1.2` with the subnet mask `255.255.255.240`, your subnet is the IP range of `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.15` (although the lowest and highest are generally not used for devices as they have special functions). If your IP was `192.168.1.53` your network would be the range `192.168.1.48` to `192.168.1.63`.

Notice how both these sets contain 16 unique addresses? The subnet also defined how *large* the subnet is because it defines how many IP addresses are available.

### And now, with Binary

Finally, to paraphrase [Manaf Abo.Rous](https://superuser.com/questions/186850/what-is-the-essentialness-of-subnet-mask/186852#186852)'s answer, let's look at the binary.

We'll start by using the mask `255.255.255.0`, here it is in binary:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000
```

So given your IP you know that every IP in local network matches those first 24 ones, so lets check your IP (`192.168.1.2`) in binary:

```
11000000 10101000 00000001 00000010
```

Now, we only look where the 1's in the subnet are, to get your subnet number:

```
11000000 10101000 00000001 --------
```

And now we know *every* IP in your local network starts with your subnet number, and can have anything in the missing values at the end.

Finally, lets look at a second example, using IP `192.168.1.53` and subnet `255.255.255.240`:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000  [subnet] 
11000000 10101000 00000001 00110101  [IP]
11000000 10101000 00000001 0011----  [subnet number]
```

And again, your local IP's would have anything in the last four binary values - which are `0000`,`0001`,etc up to `1111` - or in decimal `0` to `15` - but remember they would have `0011` in front to make a full byte, so really the IP's available are `00110000` (48), `00110001` (49) and so on up to `00111111`, which is 63.

Comment: Hmmm, just come back to have a re-read of my post and realised it really is painfully long. Sorry about that, but I'm not sure I can parr it down without damaging the content...

Comment: Wow. Having seen the frankly *excellent* [SF post](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) that MarkM linked to from the comments on this question my answer actually looks small in comparison... which is worrying...

Answer (score 5):

The subnet mask is used to identify your network IP.

Applying the [logical AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_and) operation on your IP Address and the Subnet Mask will output your network ip address.

in the example above

IP Address  : 11000000 10101000 00000001 00000010  = 192.168.1.2

Subnet Mask : 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000  = 255.255.255.0

AND Result  : 11000000 10101000 00000001 00000000  = 192.168.1.0 = You Network Address

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet_mask)

Comment: Nice technical explanation :P  Not too much information

Comment: +1 this is the real answer of how the hardware gets the network information from

Answer (score 1):

A subnet mask is used for routing IP packets.

Basically, you take your destination IP address, `and` it with the mask and, it it matches a value, you use that route.

For example, here's one bit of my output from `netstat -nrv`:

```
Destination      Netmask          Gateway         Interface
192.168.182.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.182.1   192.168.182.1
```

That means that *any* IP address of the form `192.168.182.x` will route based on this rule, because any address of that format, when `and`-ed with `255.255.255.0` (the netmask) will give `192.168.182.0` (the destination).

Similarly, a default route would be:

```
Destination      Netmask          Gateway         Interface
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          9.185.149.1     9.185.149.52
```

since *any* address `and`-ed with `0.0.0.0` gives `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: what is -ed here

Comment: and-ed : this means perform a bitwise and between two numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations#AND)

Comment: Someone asking about subnet masks is likely to get confused when you start talking about routes...

Comment: @Java - Past tense of the boolean operation "and"

Answer (score 1):

The subnet mask splits the IP into two sections, a network (or subnet) part and a host part.  The preceding comments illustrate that nicely.

Anything where the network part of the IP is the same can communicate without having to go "through" a router.  The host part of the IP must be different for each device, of course.

If you had 4 computers with these IP/subnet masks set:

`host_11 - 192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0`

`host_12 - 192.168.2.2/255.255.255.0`

`gateway - 192.168.2.3/255.255.255.0`

`host_21 - 192.168.3.5/255.255.255.0`

only the first 3 could communicate.  The fourth would not respond, because it is not on the same subnet.

"Default gateway" is a fancy name for a router, and it needs to be on the same network.  You might have seen ipconfig output where there is no default gateway.  That means no routing; i.e. communication can only happen between IP's on that network.

Keeping with our example:

`host_11 - 192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0; default gateway 192.168.2.3`

`host_12 - 192.168.2.2/255.255.255.0; default gateway 192.168.2.3`

`gateway - 192.168.2.3/255.255.255.0`

`host_21 - 192.168.3.5/255.255.255.0; default gateway 192.168.2.3`

If 192.168.2.1 wanted to talk to say, 192.168.3.5, it would end up that 192.168.2.3 picks up that traffic, and then forwards it.  (Routing is forwarding.)  192.168.2.3 would need a second IP that is set to something like 192.168.3.1/255.255.255.0.  Then, 192.168.3.5 would need to have it's default gateway set to something on it's subnet, which 192.168.3.1 is.

So, in all actuality, it really looks like this:

`host_11 - 192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0; default gateway 192.168.2.3`

`host_12 - 192.168.2.2/255.255.255.0; default gateway 192.168.2.3`

`gateway - first IP 192.168.2.3/255.255.255.0, second IP 192.168.3.1/255.255.255.0`

`host_21 - 192.168.3.5/255.255.255.0; default gateway 192.168.3.1`

So now the 192.168.2.X and 192.168.3.X networks can speak to each other.  Of course, they can't speak to any other network, or the Internet.  The gateway would need a third IP connected to an ISP, and have that set as it's default gateway.  The gateway then picks up non-same-network traffic from 192.168.2.X and 192.168.3.X.

You can set routing rules for situations where the gateway can't find out everything on it's own.  In this example we don't really need to since all networks are connected to the router.  However, in situations where you have a network with multiple routers (default gateways), or "networks behind networks", then routing rules have to be specified.  That's getting into some advanced stuff.  I hope this was helpful.